# Wordpress send email with callback and response using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, email

Unfortunately I am a beginner in WP code writing and I am trying to implement a custom mail send form in WP whit a response but I have no idea how to do it.

I have the following code in witch "send_carrier_email_callback" should be the e-mail send function:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_send_carrier_email', 'send_carrier_email_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_carrier_email', 'send_carrier_email_callback');

function send_carrier_email_callback(){
    global $wpdb; 
    var_dump($_POST);
        add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );

$to = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['carriertittle']." állásjelentkezés";
$body = $_POST['massage'];

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body );

// Reset content-type to avoid conflicts -- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23578
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );

function wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}
}




function get_carier_ation_callback() {
    global $wpdb; 
    $post_id = $_POST['career'];
    $meta = get_post_meta($post_id, "slide_options");
    $meta_values =$meta[0];
    $args = array (
        'p'                      => $post_id,
        'post_type'              => array( 'enetix_career' ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post(); ?>

            <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                    jQuery('#applybutton').click(function(){
                        jQuery('#applyform').toggle("slow");
                    });

                    jQuery('#carrieremailsend').click(function(){
                        var career_id = jQuery('#carrierid').val();
                        var name = jQuery('#name').val();
                        var email = jQuery('#email').val();
                        var massage = jQuery('#massage').val();

                        var data = {
                        action: 'send_carrier_email',
                        career: career_id,
                        name: name,
                        email: email,
                        massage: massage
                        }

                        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {



                        });
                    });
                });
```

In the "jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response)" I should get a response if the send was successful or not.

Anyone could help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this. Hope it works for you:

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_send_carrier_email', 'send_carrier_email_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_carrier_email', 'send_carrier_email_callback');

function send_carrier_email_callback(){
    global $wpdb;
    $send_email = false;
    $to = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = 'Your subject goes here';
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $send_mail = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
    echo $send_mail; //returns true or false
}

function get_carier_ation_callback() {
    global $wpdb; 
    $post_id = $_POST['career'];
    $meta = get_post_meta($post_id, "slide_options");
    $meta_values =$meta[0];
    $args = array (
        'p'                      => $post_id,
        'post_type'              => array( 'enetix_career' ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post(); ?>

            <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                    jQuery('#applybutton').click(function(){
                        jQuery('#applyform').toggle("slow");
                    });

                    jQuery('#carrieremailsend').click(function(){
                        var career_id = jQuery('#carrierid').val();
                        var name = jQuery('#name').val();
                        var email = jQuery('#email').val();
                        var massage = jQuery('#massage').val();
                        $.ajax({
                          type: 'post',
                          url: ajaxurl,
                          data: {action: 'send_carrier_email_callback', name: name, email: email, message: message},
                          success: function(response){
                            console.log(response); //your response goes here
                            if(response === true){
                                  //color your div or whatever element green
                            }else{
                                  //color your div red 
                            }
                          }
                        });

                    });
                });
```

Comment: infortunately in "jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response)" have to get some response like coloring a div red if not sent or green if sent

Comment: I don't see any div or html elements in your question code. However I've updated my answer a bit. Check the modifications in wp_mail function and in $.ajax succes function.